# My Mouse and Keyboard Don't Work With Tails

Tags: configuration, tails, help

Update:

I Finally got Tails installed to my USB flash drive. When Tails loads to the welcome screen I can't do anything because, the Mouse and Keyboard don't work.

How do I get them to work?

Thank You.

I downloaded Tails. I really do not know how to get it on my USB flash drive.
the only option I see it burn to DVD.
I don't want it on DVD, I bought this USB flash drive just for Tails.

Also, The tails verify keeps saying the files are corrupt and can not be fixed.
I deleted it, then I download it again, it said the same thing. I deleted it again, then I tried again. The download stopped at 72% I waited to see if it would restart, then it said the download stopped responding. reporting this issue to Microsoft, then it closed.

So, I tried again, this time my internet security blocked the download saying a download file contains a Trojan Virus.

If, and when I can get a good download of Tails, how do I get it on to my USB flash drive?
If someone could please give me detailed step-by-step instructions I would greatly appreciate your time doing so.

Thank You.

Comment: Did you try the [installation instructions](https://tails.boum.org/install/index.en.html)? If so, what operating system are you using and where did it get stuck? The Windows instructions explain how to load it on a USB drive.

Comment: That's where I was. It only tells me how to download it, verify the download. It doesn't tell me how to get it on my USB flash drive. I am using Windows 10 64bit, Version 1809, OS Build 17763.437

Comment: In section 1.3, there’s a green button that says “Next: Install Tails (3/5)”. It’s above the optional GPG verification step. It looks like one of the download links, but it actually goes to the step that explains how to install Tails to the USB stick with Etcher.

Comment: That button is not there. The only thing I see above the GPG  skip download link, and verify Tails 1.13.3 button. I'm using tor browser to do this, could that be an issue?

Comment: I finally got tails installed on to my USB flash drive, but when it loads the welcome screen the mouse and keyboard don't work so I can't do anything. Why doesn't the mouse and keyboard work? How do I get them to work?

Comment: That question might be better for the SuperUser site instead of this one. You should maybe try asking there. But in the future please try to make a new question rather than changing your existing one. This way the new one gets seen by more people, and other people with the same problem as your original one can find the old one too.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this site: https://tails.boum.org/support/known_issues/
For me the internal keyboard of the Microsoft Surface Laptop 2 doesen't work. I use a bluetooth keyboard with an USB dongle.

For the installation process I followed this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QmBfmv6Wn9E&t=136s and also used etcher to flash the .img-file to the USB drive. I had no issues during the download or the verification of the downloaded file.

It's a really late answer, but I just saw your post. If you were not able to fix your preblems yet, I hope this helps.